# Java constructors pattern

Tags: java, guice

I use the pattern quite a lot:

```
class Blah
  int a;   
  double b;   
  String c;   
  Date d;   

  public Blah(int a, double b, String c, Date d) {
      super(); // possibly   
      this.a = a;   
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
      this.d = d;
  }
```

This is indeed a great deal of boilerplate for something so simple.  I was thinking of a generic object factory to do this with introspection, but this feels very evil (special cases, inheritance, and speed issues). Guice could be used and the constructor skipped altogether, but then manual object creation is going to be ugly.

Is this something I will have to live with in Java or is there a way to avoid this boilerplate?

Comment: i don't quite clear what's your question.

Comment: It's a lot of boilerplate code indeed, but then again, Eclipse can just generate this in the blink of an eye :)

Comment: Yes, we live with this kind of boilerplate in Java.

Comment: @lichengwu: see the last sentence (I am asking whether there is a way/technique to avoid the "this.x = x" lines.)

Comment: @Heuster: Indeed, I use Eclipse and I do, do that, but my question is still whether the lines can be avoided, something like Myclass myclass = GenFactory.create(MyClass.class, a, b, c, d);

Comment: The argument about "Eclipse can generate it for you" can only be expounded by a beginner. What about refactoring, about renaming the parameter variable, about changing the type of the property, about getter/setter ordering, formatting, etc. What about debugging, when you *do* have to check what exactly is going on in the setter, but focusing your attention on the right one among 37 others is a nightmare? Etc.

Comment: Lol, the argument of having 38 setters smells like perfect code design

Comment: @Marko, how can I upvote your comment twice? :-)  That makes a perfect point.  Code generation actually compounds the problem since it is so easy to generate (smelly) code...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, in fact there are IDEs which handle parameter variable renaming, change of types, getter-setter ordering and formatting :) IntelliJ IDEA is the one. But I cannot disagree that supporting such classes is tedious work. Scala, for example, makes such things sooo simple and easy.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Scala and pretty much every other language under the Sun :)

Comment: @Heuster You mean, if I have a complex GUI component which depends on exactly 38 distinct services, like the Service Tier beans, Validation Beans, various collaborator objects, etc., all injected by Spring, that this is bad design? Please offer a suggestion how this can be improved without introducing even more boilerplate and sweeping the issues under a rug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Lombok (http://projectlombok.org/)

You can generate getters, setters and constructors with mere annotations.

Comment: The demo is impressive, but I'm just waiting to find about all the pitfalls :)

Comment: I've always wondered, what is the point of using getters and setters for private members if you are doing absolutely no verification? Why not just have public members (even more so when the fields are final as well)? I get that you are separating implementation from interface, but if the setters and getters are directly linked to the member variable names, then that kinda defeats the purpose, no?

Comment: @Supericy Absolotely agree on that one. I have advocated that position several times in an SO answer, usually ended up with negative votes. Their arguments: all the standard crap about "validation" which never happens in reality, subclasses "overriding" a setter, etc.

Comment: @Supericy There is a practical answer for that: lots of frameworks use JavaBeans conventions to access objects (JSP, JSF, Spring, ...). So declaring `public String id` does not make `id` accesible, but doing `public String getId()` will. Anyway, you should be careful and not expose things that do not need to be exposed.

Comment: Lombok looks very impressive and answers my questions perfectly.  I would, however, love to know what magic happens underneath.

Comment: @Supericy No, it doesn't defeat the purpose. The Getters and Setters are there to give you the opportunity to add verification or functionality later or to work with Interfaces or to use Proxies or or or... I currently work in an envorinment with public members and they've become a major PITA...

Comment: @Nicktar Most modern frameworks handle public fields just as well (Spring and Hibernate, for example). But I am *sincerely* interested in hearing your real-life bad experience with public fields. I personally have never met with a situation where it was appropriate to insert verification into a setter as opposed to a unit test or a bean validation scheme.

Comment: @Supericy, MarkoTopolnik You're so right. Public fields especially shine when you strive to make your objects immutable. Btw, Lombok's disadvantage is in that it only really usable with Eclipse. And Eclipse itself is not very usable after working with IntelliJ IDEA...

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Exactly, that was even implied by the demo... they have specially tailored support for Eclipse and the command-line `javac`, and that's where it stops. So it's a custom, non-repeatable build scheme which locks you into an IDE. Very, very bad for public projects, and an unsound choice even for a company-internal project.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Short version since it's kind of offtopic here: I maintain a homegrown persistence framework that would have been replaced by a modern open source solution long ago by using the existing classes as a fassade to the new one if the existing classes hadn't been designed using public members (which prevents the use of lazy loading too), as these can't be delegated.

Comment: @Nicktar But Hibernate does pull off all that with public fields... I think it's loadtime weaving (just like AspectJ), but I never checked.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But since Hibernate (and every other ORM framework) isn't a 1:1 match additional work is needed to make sure every old piece of code (relying on the quirks of the homegrown solution) will not break.

Comment: @Nicktar Sure... that would probably be unavoidable anyway---especially if you want to use Hibernate Annotations (and you definitely should). BTW the very existence and popularity of Hibernate Annotations shows that most people don't worry about ever having to switch ORMs. For those that do, there's the JPA annotations, meaning you can use public fields *and* switch ORMs. Anyway, I see your point, and your difficulties may really be lesser with accessors, but your situtaion is very special and not a killer argument against anyone else using public fields.